# How to install ngCkeditor using npm?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am unable to install `ngCkeditor` using npm.

When i did `npm install ng-ckeditor` it is showing following error.

```
npm WARN package.json opgadminsuite@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program   Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ng-ckeditor"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code E404

 npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/ng-ckeditor
 npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'ng-ckeditor' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'opgadminsuite'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\New Adminsuite\npm-debug.log
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: install using bower  like bower install ng-ckeditor

Comment: If i will install it using bower then the folder will be created in bower_components. In that case if i will move those files to node_modules, will it work or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`bower`](https://bower.io/) to install `ng-ckeditor`.

```
npm install -g bower@latest
bower install ng-ckeditor
```

See https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor